# How to select records where numbers are between 15 and 21 from array with hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, select, hash

I'm trying to select certain hashes from an array of hashes. The idea is to get all hashes where `day_number` is between say `15` and `21`

`@importants` has the following example value:

```
[{:question_content=>"<p>Belangrijke vraag</p>\r\n", :answer_content=>"test-content", :day_number=>1}, {:question_content=>"<p>belangrijk verhaal</p>\r\n", :answer_content=>"test-content", :day_number=>15}]
```

I try to get all elements between 15 and 21 to a new array by running this code.

```
@importants.select {|important| important["day_number"] > 14 && important["day_number"] <= 21 }
```

but it returns `undefined method`>' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey In hash key is symbol and you tried as string, so please try this

```
@importants.select {|important| important[:day_number] > 14 && important[:day_number] <= 21 }
```

also this is interesting solution, try it

```
@importants.select {|important| (15..21).include?(important[:day_number])}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use symbol keys inside of `@importants` array, but try to access them as strings in your `select` query. Strictly speaking, that is not the same thing. Try this:

```
@importants.select {|important| important[:day_number] > 14 && important[:day_number] <= 21 }
```

Comment: Nice, the question was answered at the same time by someone else but thanks for your hint. yet it seems that my misstakes are in those small things :(